# bundle.js TypeError: Cannot read propertied of undefined (reading PriceIndexationDataControlStandard)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pcf

I am developing a React component via Microsoft PCF Framework and I have encountered a very strange error out of nowhere. I was changing only typescript, not even running any build commands etc. and suddenly the rendering of my component stopped working. I can see error in console: [Error screenshot in conosle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoQop.png)

The PriceIndexationDataControlStandard is my exported class, I am not sure what could I have done wrong, nor how to fix it.

It seems that the component is undefined in the bundle.js - I believe the framework uses webpack internally for bundling. Does anyone experienced something like this?

Thank you

Edit: running npm build throws no error. neither npm rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was my mistake. I accidentally removed setting of properties in one of constructors of my wrapper classes.